# Blender 3D printing

Tags: 3d, blender

I am trying to create .stl files from Blender to print in 3D. I have created a script that creates a curve. This curve I then rotated and get a tubelike mesh. The dimensions in Blender are correct (and metric).

Now if I export this as .stl. and import in the 3D print software (Cubify) the dimensions are always wrong. And my print has 0 mm<sup>3</sup> volume.

I went back to Blender added a Solidify modifier to the mesh with 1 mm thickness (the rest of the options I left default).
Again in Cubify I have 0 mm3 Volume.

My questions:

1. Is there a **good** tutorial that can walk me through the process of creating curves, meshes with python and then transform them into something 3D printable?
2. How can I solve the dimension problem? I already printed quite a few pieces, but it was always a headache. And I would like to know if this could be a .stl problem and if so how to solve it.
3. Is there aother option to add a 1 mm thickness to a mesh besides the Solidify Modifier?

Comment: Do you get the same problem, when you export, say, a simple cube? Can you post the Python script you use to create your curves?

Answer (score 2):

On your dimension problem:

If you're using Blender for 3D printing, you will want to remember to install the 3D Printing Toolbox or you will get all kinds of errors about nonmanifold objects.

Your first step should be to set up your default scene by changing your units from the default "Units" to millimeters, and then set the grid options to show you the size of your print volume.

You shouldn't add a thickness to a mesh. Start with a cylinder or something like that already, and then SUBTRACT from it with another, smaller cylinder. Then you will find yourself with a hallow tube object like you are going for.